# How do I correct this error in Oracle shown here?

Tags: oracle-data-integrator, data-integration

For those who use Oracle Data Integration - ODI.

I need a help, I have create the Physical topologies, data sources, logical topologies and models.

When I create mapping in order to transfer data from source to destination, I get this error :

> java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/xml/bind/JAXBException
>
> at oracle.odi.domain.runtime.common.GenerationInfo.convertObjectToXml(GenerationInfo.java:99)
> at oracle.odi.domain.runtime.common.AbstractRuntimeStep.setGenerationInfo(AbstractRuntimeStep.java:387)
> at oracle.odi.domain.mapping.generator.MappingGenerator.generateExecutableDetails(MappingGenerator.java:894)
> at oracle.odi.domain.mapping.generator.MappingGenerator.generateSession(MappingGenerator.java:372)
> at oracle.odi.domain.mapping.generator.MappingGenerator.generateSession(MappingGenerator.java:331)
> at oracle.odi.ui.mapping.MappingExecutionDialog$1.doInTransaction(MappingExecutionDialog.java:336)
> at oracle.odi.core.persistence.transaction.support.TransactionTemplate.execute(TransactionTemplate.java:100)
> at oracle.odi.ui.mapping.MappingExecutionDialog.doExecution(MappingExecutionDialog.java:331)
> at oracle.odi.ui.mapping.MappingExecutionDialog.dialogOkActionHook(MappingExecutionDialog.java:174)
> at oracle.cef.ui.definition.DialogDefinitionNode$1.vetoableChange(DialogDefinitionNode.java:347)
> at java.desktop/java.beans.VetoableChangeSupport.fireVetoableChange(VetoableChangeSupport.java:381)
> at java.desktop/java.beans.VetoableChangeSupport.fireVetoableChange(VetoableChangeSupport.java:274)
> at oracle.bali.ewt.dialog.JEWTDialog.fireVetoableChange(JEWTDialog.java:1541)
> at oracle.bali.ewt.dialog.JEWTDialog.dismissDialog(JEWTDialog.java:1571)
> at oracle.bali.ewt.dialog.JEWTDialog$UIListener.actionPerformed(JEWTDialog.java:1964)
> at java.desktop/javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:1967)
> at java.desktop/javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2308)
> at java.desktop/javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:405)
> at java.desktop/javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:262)
> at java.desktop/javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:279)
> at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6635)
> at java.desktop/javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3342)
> at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6400)
> at java.desktop/java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2263)
> at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:5011)
> at java.desktop/java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2321)
> at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4843)
> at java.desktop/java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4918)
> at java.desktop/java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4547)
> at java.desktop/java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4488)
> at java.desktop/java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2307)
> at java.desktop/java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2772)
> at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4843)
> at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:772)
> at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:721)
> at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:715)
> at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
> at java.base/java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:85)
> at java.base/java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:95)
> at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$5.run(EventQueue.java:745)
> at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$5.run(EventQueue.java:743)
> at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
> at java.base/java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:85)
> at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:742)
> at oracle.javatools.internal.ui.EventQueueWrapper._dispatchEvent(EventQueueWrapper.java:169)
> at oracle.javatools.internal.ui.EventQueueWrapper.dispatchEvent(EventQueueWrapper.java:151)
> at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:203)
> at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:124)
> at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:117)
> at java.desktop/java.awt.WaitDispatchSupport$2.run(WaitDispatchSupport.java:190)
> at java.desktop/java.awt.WaitDispatchSupport$4.run(WaitDispatchSupport.java:235)
> at java.desktop/java.awt.WaitDispatchSupport$4.run(WaitDispatchSupport.java:233)
> at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
> at java.desktop/java.awt.WaitDispatchSupport.enter(WaitDispatchSupport.java:233)
> at java.desktop/java.awt.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:1070)
> at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.show(Component.java:1716)
> at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.setVisible(Component.java:1663)
> at java.desktop/java.awt.Window.setVisible(Window.java:1031)
> at java.desktop/java.awt.Dialog.setVisible(Dialog.java:1005)
> at oracle.bali.ewt.dialog.JEWTDialog.runDialog(JEWTDialog.java:399)
> at oracle.bali.ewt.dialog.JEWTDialog.runDialog(JEWTDialog.java:360)
> at oracle.cef.ui.adapter.DialogAdapterImpl.displayDialog(DialogAdapterImpl.java:155)
> at oracle.cef.ui.Framework.displayDialog(Framework.java:284)
> at oracle.odi.ui.SnpsFcpActionAdapter.handleEvent(SnpsFcpActionAdapter.java:336)
> at oracle.ide.controller.IdeAction$ControllerDelegatingController.handleEvent(IdeAction.java:1488)
> at oracle.ide.controller.IdeAction.performAction(IdeAction.java:663)
> at oracle.ide.controller.IdeAction.actionPerformedImpl(IdeAction.java:1159)
> at oracle.ide.controller.IdeAction.actionPerformed(IdeAction.java:618)
> at java.desktop/javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:1967)
> at java.desktop/javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2308)
> at java.desktop/javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:405)
> at java.desktop/javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:262)
> at java.desktop/javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:279)
> at java.desktop/java.awt.AWTEventMulticaster.mouseReleased(AWTEventMulticaster.java:298)
> at java.desktop/java.awt.AWTEventMulticaster.mouseReleased(AWTEventMulticaster.java:297)
> at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6635)
> at java.desktop/javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3342)
> at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6400)
> at java.desktop/java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2263)
> at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:5011)
> at java.desktop/java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2321)
> at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4843)
> at java.desktop/java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4918)
> at java.desktop/java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4547)
> at java.desktop/java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4488)
> at java.desktop/java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2307)
> at java.desktop/java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2772)
> at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4843)
> at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:772)
> at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:721)
> at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:715)
> at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
> at java.base/java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:85)
> at java.base/java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:95)
> at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$5.run(EventQueue.java:745)
> at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$5.run(EventQueue.java:743)
> at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
> at java.base/java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:85)
> at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:742)
> at oracle.javatools.internal.ui.EventQueueWrapper._dispatchEvent(EventQueueWrapper.java:169)
> at oracle.javatools.internal.ui.EventQueueWrapper.dispatchEvent(EventQueueWrapper.java:151)
> at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:203)
> at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:124)
> at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:113)
> at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:109)
> at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
> at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:90)

I hope someone can help me.

I have followed all the pre-requisites but the error remain.